# Vim Regex: Capture *first* instance of word between characters

Tags: regex, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

My organization has an in-house language, with syntax like:

```
cmo/create/mo1///tri
createpts/brick/xyz/2,2,2/0.,0.,0./1.,1.,1./1,1,1
```

I am writing a Vim syntax file, and would like to capture the *first* instance of a word enclosed by two characters (in this case, `/`), **without** capturing the characters themselves.

I.e., the regex would capture, from the lines above,

```
create
brick
```

My solution so far is to use this pattern:

```
[,/=" "].\{-}[,/=" "]
```

But from `/this/and/this/and/this`, it will capture **`/this/`**`and`**`/this/`**`and`**`/this/`**.

As you can see, the issue is two-fold: (i) my current solution is greedy, and (ii) captures the `/` characters as well, when I just want the words enclosed by these.

Thanks!

Comment: Use positive lookbehind and positive lookahead. I believe vim syntax is `\@<=` for positive lookbehind and `\@=` for positive lookahead

Comment: Work with `\zs` match resetter `^(?:\w+)?/\zs\w+\(/\)\@=`

Comment: ^, and you can use `[^/]*` to avoid the lookahead and `\w*` to avoid the group.

Comment: `[^/]*` doesn't ensure that you have `/` as the next immediate character e.g. in `/test`.  @Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
^[^\/]\+\/\zs[^\/]\+\ze\/
```

- `^` anchor the search to the BOL,
- `[^\/]\+` one or more non-slash characters, as many as possible,
- `\/` a slash,
- `\zs` start the match here,
- `[^\/]\+` one or more non-slash characters, as many as possible.

Comment: Again this doesn't ensure that you have the word enclosed by slash marks.

Comment: Well… just add `\ze\/`.